# How can I convert a time from date in query?

Tags: php, mysql, date

Im trying to convert a timestamp formt in my mysql to date and order by this date.

```
  $query =  mysql_query("SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(banfrom ,'%d/%c/%Y') as time FROM ab_list ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0,50");
```

Its not showing the date when I try to do like this:

```
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
 echo $info['time'];
    }
```

How can I do for showing the date in the echo and oder by this date??

Thanks guyss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to convert timestamp into date first before using `DATE_FORMAT` which converts date into string.

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(banfrom), '%d/%c/%Y') AS Time
```

and when you want to order your record, just directly sort the timestamp column,

```
ORDER BY banfrom DESC
```

- [FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)